# using InStr with listbox items

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm looking for some specific strings who are in a listbox.
(List contain 4 strings who are parts of some items of the listbox)

```
Sub Auto_Select_Report(List As Object)
For i = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    For J = 0 To List.Count
        If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.List(i), List(J)) Then
            MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.List(i))
        End If
    Next J
Next i
End Sub
```

But nothing work, I get the error :

> Object required

Someone know why or know how to do that ?

Comment: Your tagged this as VBA/Excel, but your link points to VB.Net. There is no `ToString`-method in VBA

Comment: Damn .... You right. That explain a lot. Thanks. do you have any idea how to do that with VBA ?

Comment: thanks FaneDuru, but I already try and the error remain the same

Comment: For VBA it's `ListBox1.List(i)` for the specific item and `ListBox1.ListCount` for the number of items.

Comment: that's right thank's Hel OWeen, I just edit my code but I'm still stuck with "Object required" error. I will update my post with the new code

Comment: Which line throws that error? What exactly is `List`? How do you call the sub? What do you pass as parameter?

Comment: I'm calling the Sub like that : Auto_Select_Report List:=regList  
reglist is Object type and contain 4 strings.

Comment: the error target line if the one with the InStr

Comment: As an `object` can be everything. Also, an object cannot have "4 strings".  How exactly have your defined it and how do you add the strings into it? You need to show the code that calls your sub.

Comment: Try `CStr(List(J))` instead of `List(J)` in the InStr line. `InStr` expects [two string variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) and you are passing a variable of type `Object`. VB _does_ some data type conversion magic behind the scenes, but best practice is to not rely on that, but rather do the conversion yourself if needed. And on an unrelated note: if the search should start at the beginning of a string, you can omit the first parameter: `InStr(mainStr, findStr)` is equivalent to `InStr(1, mainStr, findStr)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself and thanks to all your help.

I finaly delete my Sub with the Object parameter to replace it with this code :

```
For line = 2 To src.Worksheets("Paramétrage").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1 ' Loop inside workbook Bilan
    For i = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.ListCount - 1 ' Loop inside listbox
        Ref = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.List(i)
        If InStr(1, Ref, "_" & src.Worksheets("Paramétrage").Cells(line, 1) & "_") Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bilan_SMF").ListBox1.Selected(i) = True 'select the item if found
        End If
    Next i
Next line
```

Everything is working fine, thanks all